# could not be found or has no tests in Junit

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I am trying to test setting application using **JunitTestcase**.My class extends **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2**. But while executing I am getting this error:

> 01-12 17:22:11.519: WARN/TestGrouping(2942): Invalid Package: '' could
>   not be found or has no tests 01-12 17:22:11.539:
>
> INFO/ActivityManager(1620): Force stopping package com.android.settings uid=1000

Can any one suggest a solution for this?.

Comment: Post your test class code will help others find your problem.

Comment: A similar problem and another solution is also posted in [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346734/trying-to-run-android-junit-tests-in-eclipse-fails/10024250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the app to be tested in the AndroidManifest of the testing project.. that might be missing.

Comment: yes , I have specified it.Setting app is having shared userId is that a problem?

Comment: @VIJESH  What do you mean your app has a "shared userId"?  Where did you specify that?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, after spending two days I solved it..

Test class path : app/src/androidTest/java/your-pkg-name/example_classTest.java

java file path : app/src/main/java/your-pkg-name/example_class.java

and you should clearly define below code in your app gradle

```
android{

      sourceSets {

         androidTest {
              java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
          }


        }

 }
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I tracked the problem down to my gradle file.  I needed the following in there:

```
aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
```