# AssertionFailedError: <class> has no public constructor

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio

I am working with Android Studio and I need to add a unit tests to my project.
I read various tutorials, but nothing hepled me.
My problem is:
**TestXMLParser.java:**

```
public class TestXMLParser extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HomePageActivity> {

public TestXMLParser(Class<HomePageActivity> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    //Controller.init((Activity)getContext());
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}

public void testTrue() throws Exception {
    assertTrue(true);
}
...
}
```

When I run it, I see this message:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Class cz.cvut.kosapp.jUnitTests.TestXMLParser has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

I really do not know why.
Other jUnit tests works well, for example when I use:

```
public class TestXMLParser extends AndroidTestCase { ...
```

in header, this works and tests are running correctly.
**But** I need use the Context (as a Activity) to run other code (in Controller class).

Do you have any idea how fix it?
**Thank you for your comments.**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to add either a default constructor or a constructor which takes a `String` as a parameter.  Adding the following default constructor with a call to the base class constructor should work:

```
public TestXMLParser() {
    super(HomePageActivity.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but it is not correct answer.
This constructor is not  avalable in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

Comment: You are correct - ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 doesn't expose a default constructor.  Instead, you make a default constructor for your class and then call super with valid parameters for one of the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 constructors - one of them which accepts a class - and you pass in the class under test. I found something similar here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346734/trying-to-run-android-junit-tests-in-eclipse-fails

Comment: Android Studio moves so quickly that half of the published books that you have spent money on and a lot of the internet examples simply don't work.